# Search optimization when data owner is someone else

Tags: java, search, spring-mvc

In my project, we have 2 REST calls which take too much time, so we are planning to optimize that. Here is how it works currently - we make 1st call to system A and then pass the response to system B for further processing. Once we get the response from system B, we have to manipulate it further before passing it to UI layer and this entire process takes lot of time. We planned on using Solr/Lucene but since we are not the data owners, we can't implement that. Can someone please shed some light on how best this can be handled? We are using Spring MVC and Spring webflow. Thanks in advance!!

[EDIT:] This is not the actual scenario and I am writing this as an example for better understanding. Think of this as making a store locator call for a particular zip to get a list of 100 stores and then sending those 100 stores to another call to get a list of inventory etc. So, this list of stores would change for every zip code and also the inventory there.

Comment: How does solr / lucene help ? Is the bottleneck in waiting for the response or in post processing time ?

Comment: "take too much time" is a bit broad. I'd suggest digging into the issue to determine exactly where the slow down is occurring. Profilers can be very useful. You may also want to put timing instrumentation in your code to help pinpoint where the slow down is occurring. When you get more specific details, pls post them.

Comment: @DeepakBala - Bottleneck is in waiting for the response.

Comment: @SteveWall - we have timing instrumentation code and we have implemented caching too but its just that the upstream systems' response isn't fast enough. Please see "edit" for the kind of scenario I have in my project. I'll keep looking for options and would update the question on finding the apt solution.

Comment: Maybe the size of the request to the back-end system is causing delays. Do you have access to the dev staff of that system? One thought is to break your request into smaller chunks and spawn multi threads to send the various smaller requests.

Comment: @SteveWall - We do have access to their dev staff but they aren't eager to change something at their end because, I guess we might not be their only customers. As you suggested, we can think about breaking the request into smaller chunks and see if we can achieve something? Thank you for your input.

Comment: I was a bit unclear how you might be able to leverage their dev staff. Not to necessarily change their code, but to possibly provide insight into how to most effectively use the service. You could describe your scenario and maybe they could give pointers on how to tweak your interaction. Or they could do an explain plan on their DB to see if any optimizations could be realized. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

If your queries parameters to System A / System B are frequently the same you can add a cache framework to your code. If you use Spring3, you can use the cache easily with an @Cacheable annotation on your code  calling SystemA. See : 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

The cache subsystem will cache the result including processing code.

Comment: Query parameters are different. We are already doing caching but that's not much helpful.